# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 3)

Tags: python, pygame

I've got some code that currently displays a random number of randomly coloured rectangles at random points around the screen. Now, I want to make them move randomly. I have a for loop that is generating the random colours, x, y, etc. and also the direction that the squares will move in. Further down in my code, I have another for loop (this one contained within the main game loop) that displays the squares and interprets the random direction so they can move. However, when I try to run the program, it gives me the error described in the title. What am I doing wrong?

```
randpop = random.randint(10, 20)

fps = 100

px = random.randint(50, 750)
py = random.randint(50, 750)
pxp = px + 1
pyp = py + 1
pxm = px - 1
pym = py - 1
moves_list = [pxp, pyp, pxm, pym]

population = []
for _ in range(0, randpop):
    pcol = random.choice(colour_list)
    px = random.randint(50, 750)
    py = random.randint(50, 750)
    direction = random.choice(moves_list)
    population.append((px, py, pcol))

[...]

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    screen.fill(GREY)

    for px, py, pcol, direction in population:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, pcol, (px, py, 50, 50))

        print(direction)
        if direction == pxp:
            px += 1
        if direction == pyp:
            py += 1
        if direction == pxm:
            px -= 1
        if direction == pym:
            py -= 1

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Which line gives the error? What is the stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `for`-loop you expect that the tuple size is 4:

> ```py
> for px, py, pcol, direction in population:
> ```

But when you set up the list of tuples, then you have forgotten `direction`, so the tuple size is just 3. This causes the error.
Add `direction` to the tuple:

<s>`population.append((px, py, pcol))`</s>

```py
population.append((px, py, pcol, direction))
```

---

If you want to make the rectangles move, then you've to update the data in the list. e.g.:

```py
for i, (px, py, pcol, direction) in enumerate(population):

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, pcol, (px, py, 50, 50))

    print(direction)
    if direction == pxp:
        px += 1
    if direction == pyp:
        py += 1
    if direction == pxm:
        px -= 1
    if direction == pym:
        py -= 1

    population[i] = (px, py, pcol, direction)
```

Comment: Thanks! This does make the program run properly, and the error is gone. However, now it only runs for a few seconds before getting this error and stopping: for px, py, pcol, direction in population:
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object

Comment: @DuckMcFuddle Sorry, but I can't reproduce this. Note, the rectangles leave the screen, but continue to move. I recommend to implement a game logic which handles that.

Comment: Whoops, I had missed something in your code. It's working well now and I've even implemented some code that prevents the rectangles from flying off the screen. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This line is the cause of the issue:

```
for px, py, pcol, direction in population:
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, pcol, (px, py, 50, 50))
```

And if you look before that, this is actually the real problem:

```
population.append((px, py, pcol))
```

I assume you wanted to type `population.append((px, py, pcol, direction))`